# redirect in before action is running infinitely in yii2

Tags: yii2

i have added access filter to web.php and in login action consists following code

public function actionLogin() {

```
    return $this->render('loginform', ['model' => $model, 'iv' => $iv, 'key' => $key]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2 you don't have to do workarounds like that to achieve checking if user is logged in. Yii2 has own [Access Controll](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html) behaviours, which will do all for you.

To use it, add in your controller this behaviour:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@']
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

It will check if user whos trying access all actions in this controller is logged in. For more options you should look here: [YIi2 - Access Control Filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html)

Comment: i have tried the above access control filter but after login its not getting directed to expected page it remains in the login page itself

Comment: So it's generally your login action, access rule worked fine.

Comment: Access rule worked fine but once user logins he is not redirected to expected url

Comment: Yes, but it depends on your `actionLogin`, not access rule.

Comment: but the code in my login action does not contain anything of infinite redirection

Comment: Remove this `beforeAction` you created (full, just delete it) AND if it's still not working, update question with `actionLogin` code.

Comment: i have posted another question which shows code for login action

Comment: Don't make additional questions to same problem. Edit current question with code. One question - did you added access controll to controller where's `actionLogin()`?

Comment: access controll is in web.php so it would be globally applied to all controllers

Comment: So did you write exceptions to allow not logged user access to `actionLogin()`?

Comment: So that's your problem with infinity loops. Unlogged user trying to access login action, which is protected from unlogged users.